# After adding plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking, it prompts that the file is not included in tsconfig

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I use

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

to create a project, then I add typescript type checking to it, but my App.tsx reports the following error:

```
Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/../../../../my-app-ts/src/App.tsx` using `parserOptions.project`: <tsconfigRootDir>/tsconfig .json
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:
- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
- Change that TSConfig to include this file
- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.project
See the TypeScript ESLint docs for more info: https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/troubleshooting##i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that -tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-fileeslint
```

my .eslintrc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    project: "./tsconfig.json",
  },
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
  root: true,
};
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

my dir tree:

```
/mnt/data0/work/my-app-ts
├── README.md
├── package.json
├── public
|  ├── favicon.ico
|  ├── index.html
|  ├── logo192.png
|  ├── logo512.png
|  ├── manifest.json
|  └── robots.txt
├── src
|  ├── App.css
|  ├── App.test.tsx
|  ├── App.tsx
|  ├── index.css
|  ├── index.tsx
|  ├── logo.svg
|  ├── react-app-env.d.ts
|  ├── reportWebVitals.ts
|  └── setupTests.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── yarn.lock
```

It looks like src/App.tsx is already in the include scope, I don't know why this doesn't work, my project is created entirely by create-react-app without any other modifications.

If you have a good idea, please reply to me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: where you get this error? vscode? or in terminal

Comment: When I run npx eslint I don't get any errors, but my vscode shows problems.

Comment: I can't exactly tell you what is the problem, but you have to go in vscode setting and check for eslint and typescript extention settings. I think in the setting you put wront path for `tsconfig` but you have to see yourself and check all settings in these two extensions

Comment: I think its because of this line `<tsconfigRootDir>/../../../../my-app-ts/src/App.tsx`. its seems tsrootdir is set to different directory in vscode setting

Comment: Also remove this line is eslint, maybe it works. `tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,`

Comment: I found the same issue on github, I think it should be an issue with vscode-eslint，link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1537

Comment: Do you have another project in a `my-app-ts` folder in `<tsconfigRootDir>/../../../../`? All that backing up (`../../../../`) makes me think you've got an `App.tsx` open in your IDE you didn't intend to or that [Ali is onto something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74333776/after-adding-plugintypescript-eslint-recommended-requiring-type-checking-it-p#comment131230336_74333776).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is most likely 1-4 of:

- Update to the latest >=6.x version of all `@typescript-eslint/*` packages
- Change `parserOptions.project` from `"./tsconfig.json"` to to `true`
- Make sure that every package that you have files linted has a corresponding ESLint config and TSConfig for its `package.json`
- Make sure your TSConfig files have [`compilerOptions.jsx`](https://aka.ms/tsconfig#jsx) enabled - and generally can include `src/*.tsx` files

The first two points are because that error message was improved in later versions of `@typescript-eslint/parser` -https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#i-get-errors-telling-me-the-file-must-be-included-in-at-least-one-of-the-projects-provided- and [`project: true` was added](https://typescript-eslint.io/blog/parser-options-project-true) for more robust TSConfig lookups.

The last two points are because the only way for this error to show up when looking at a source file is for TypeScript to think that file shouldn't be included. That can happen for a `.tsx` file if TypeScript hasn't been told it should recognize JSX files. It can also happen if you accidentally set something like `"exclude": ["src"]` or `"include": ["some-typo"]`.